# Lubuntu 22.10 keeps showing NO SIGNAL after some time

Tags: lubuntu, suspend

I am using lubuntu 22.10 and my monitor goes to NO SIGNAL after some period of time, i tried:

my vga:

```
>   

lshw -c video
 > WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.  
    > *-display
    >        description: VGA compatible controller
    >        product: RocketLake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 730]
    >        vendor: Intel Corporation
    >        physical id: 2
    >        bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
    >        logical name: /dev/fb0
    >        version: 04
    >        width: 64 bits
    >        clock: 33MHz
    >        capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
    >        configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
    >        resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:137 memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff
    > ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff


sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend

xset dpms 0 0 0 && xset -dpms  && xset s off && xset s noblank
```

'false'

but still, don't have luck.
Please, any ideas?

Comment: Lubuntu is a desktop system, meaning it's format for releases is year.month. Ubuntu reserves the year format for snap only products like Ubuntu Core 22, which won't use the Lubuntu desktop being packaged in deb packages (the year format being snap only). Have you disabled the power settings & screensaver? https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/  Lubuntu also doesn't use GNOME as per many of your commands.

Comment: I didn't find how to disable it from terminal, cause i have a more than 500 workstations...